# Unable to deserialize JSON to a List

Tags: .net, json

I am unable to Deserialize my JSON.  It looks good.  Fiddler parses it, but my entity looks to be stuck in a Data field.  How do I get my data out of the Data field?  I am doing this from inside a PCL and this is the first time doing this, usually I have done this in JQuery and never have any issues.

JSON returned from REST Service:

```
{"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"Data":[{"BusinessId":2,"CommunityId":2,"BusinessName":"TestBusiness1","Address1":"12 1st Ave.","Address2":"a","City":"Fargo","State":"ND","Zip":"58102","Phone":"7019283980","Email":"b1@falala.com","WebsiteURL":"google.com","Description":"First Test Business","Active":true,"HoursOfOperation":"Mon-Fri 8am-4pm","SelectedBusinessCategories":[4],"SelectedBusinessTypes":[2,3]},{"BusinessId":8,"CommunityId":2,"BusinessName":"TestHotel1","Address1":"600 50th St.","Address2":"a","City":"Fargo","State":"ND","Zip":"58103","Phone":"7013291780","Email":"b1@falala.com","WebsiteURL":"bing.com","Description":"First Test Hotel 4 boop","Active":true,"HoursOfOperation":"Mon-Fri 8am-4pm","SelectedBusinessCategories":[7],"SelectedBusinessTypes":[2]},{"BusinessId":9,"CommunityId":2,"BusinessName":"TestShop1","Address1":"349 32nd Ave.","Address2":"a","City":"Fargo","State":"ND","Zip":"58103","Phone":"7013298109","Email":"b1@falala.com","WebsiteURL":"something.com","Description":"First Test Shop 2","Active":true,"HoursOfOperation":"Mon-Fri 8am-4pm","SelectedBusinessCategories":[6],"SelectedBusinessTypes":[2]},{"BusinessId":10,"CommunityId":2,"BusinessName":"TestBusiness2","Address1":"24345 street","Address2":"a","City":"Fargo","State":"ND","Zip":"58104","Phone":"7014298490","Email":"b1@falala.com","WebsiteURL":"bing.com","Description":"Second Test Business","Active":true,"HoursOfOperation":"Mon-Fri 8am-4pm","SelectedBusinessCategories":[5],"SelectedBusinessTypes":[3]}],"JsonRequestBehavior":0,"MaxJsonLength":null,"RecursionLimit":null}
```

Local Objects:

```
public class Item
{
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int CommunityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteURL { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }   
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
}

    public class Business : Item
{
    public int BusinessId { get { return this.ItemId; } set { this.ItemId = value; } }
    public string BusinessName { get { return this.Name; } set { this.Name = value; } }
    public int[] SelectedBusinessCategories { get; set; }
    public int[] SelectedBusinessTypes { get; set; }
    public string HoursOfOperation { get; set; }
}
```

Call REST Service and Deserialize JSON:

```
List<Business> items = new List<Business>();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebServiceURL);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(Controller);

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Business>>(content);
```

Rest Service Method:

```
public JsonResult Get()
    {
        List<Business> businesses = new BusinessContext().Businesses.Where(b => b.Active == true).ToList();

        JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
        json.Data = businesses;
        json.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        return json;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your model should be as

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }
    public int CommunityId { get; set; }
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteURL { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string HoursOfOperation { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedBusinessCategories { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedBusinessTypes { get; set; }
}
```

You may want to try http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Why can't Business inherit from Item?  Why won't that work?

Comment: @Adam Then explain how it doesn't work. I get no error when I use your code and sample json.

Comment: I just used the class that you generated in place of Business in the deserialization and got the following - to Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value ...... type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[rTownMobile.SharedLib.Models.RootObject]'. Path '', line 1, position 2463.

Comment: @Adam testing it is simple, write the json in your question to a file and test it with `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Business>>(File.ReadAllText(filename));` It works....

Comment: Ok, so that works, but why doesn't this work above.  I can't go with reading this from a file.  It has to come from the REST service.

Comment: @Adam then what you read from the rest service is not the one you posted. How can I help you with this limited info.

Comment: See the edit above for the exact string returned

Comment: @Adam it can't be the real json returned. I think it is what you see in debug window.

Comment: Ok, I made some changes.  The Jquery above is pulled out of Fiddler.  Fiddler parses fine, but my return data is stuck in the Data element of the returned JSON.  How do I get to that and deserialize it?

Comment: Now you posted a different json which is not an array/list as in your original question. Don't try to play with me...  I quit (with a -1)....... Since your question is already closed, All you can get is this.